# Is it possible to redefine PHP constants?

Tags: php, class, constants

Is it possible to redefine class constants (in PHP)?

e.g.

```
class B {
const C_ThisIsAConstant = 1;
}

class A extends B {
 self::C_ThisIsAConstant = 2;
}
```

Comment: You're asking for a variable constant. That a contradiction in terms ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, of course not.  Then they wouldn't be "constants."

Comment: You can actually: http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-redefine.php >:D

Comment: @Porges Heh. I wouldn't call runkit "redefining" so much as "beating the language into a bloody pulp".

Comment: The PECL extension is not bundled with php, so you would have to install the runkit extension.  Doing something like this is also bad..this is probably something you would use for testing/benchmarking code or other such things but /never/ in production (same with reflection).

Comment: Reflection can be used for example for RPC. However, there is _no_ reason to redefine constants, especially with such hacks.

Comment: Even though this is accepted, it is wrong - the answer is 'Yes'.

Answer (score 4):

You can't redefine "constants" because they are contant.

If you're trying to change a constant defined in an included file, then you can defining the constant before the include:

```
define ("PROCESS_NAME", "MIKE");
/* ... code ... */
include ("/path/to/included_file.php"); // also defines "PROCESS_NAME"
/* ... code ... */
```

PROCESS_NAME will be "MIKE".

Comment: After reading numerous answers on SO, most of which preach or state the obvious, this is by far the most useful answer for me - it fixed the problem (with someone else's popular code library which I do not want to dig into).  I almost overlooked this answer because of the opening statement which not only fits into the preachy/obvious category but is also incorrect. Less would be more in this case.

Answer (score 2):

First: No, it is not possible to redefine class constants. Its impossible in *every* language, because otherwise a constant wouldnt be constant.

But what you are doing is possible, because you dont redefine a class constant, instead you define a one unique constant for every class.

Comment: runkit isn't PHP core.  So, yes, you can redefine constants -- but only if you install a PECL extension.

Comment: Wether or not there are hacks: I dont feel comfortable about suggesting bad ideas.

Comment: Runkit isn't a hack, it is a tool.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class B {
    const C_ThisIsAConstant = 1;
}

class A extends B {
    const C_ThisIsAConstant = 2;
}

var_dump(A::C_ThisIsAConstant);
```

It outputs `int(2)`.

http://codepad.org/GQR9HI5M

Comment: That doesn't redefine `B::C_ThisIsAConstant`.

Answer (score 0):

I have published my framework [YAPAF](https://github.com/SchulteMarkus/YAPAF) on github.com. Let's call it alpha-state. Anyhow, YAPAF is able to change the value of a class constant (see https://github.com/SchulteMarkus/YAPAF/blob/master/tests/ManipulateConstantTest.php).