# Reinitialize constant inside a singleton class

Tags: php, oop, singleton

I wonder if it is possible to "reinitialize" somehow a constant within a singleton class.

For example:

```
class Foo {

    public static $instance = null;    

    private $status = null;

    private function __construct() { }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $c = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $c;
            self::$instance->setUp();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    // Function that will change the $status variable
    private function bar() {

        ...

        $this->status = TRUE;
    }

    private function setUp() {

        ...

        $this->bar();

        define("HELLO", $this->status);

    }

    public function baz() {

        ...

        $this->bar();
    }

}
```

So if i call **$foo->baz()** it will somehow rewrite my **HELLO** constant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to redefine PHP constants??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427699/is-it-possible-to-redefine-php-constants)

Comment: No. I know that it is impossible. But i thought i could reinitialize it by destroying the class.

Comment: You cannot destroy classes and define puts the constant in the global scope anyway. If you are desparate enough, you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-redefine.php but having to do that smells like a design flaw.

Comment: I mean by setting the instance to null. I don't get it why you give rep down for such a question.

Comment: because the question is unclear, not useful and/or doesnt show any research effort.

Comment: Well that's only your opinion.

Comment: @abc Constants are **global**. It doesn't matter where you `define` them, they're always accessible from anywhere. They're not tied to the class in any way. If you further refuse to believe this, I'm tempted to downvote you as well. >;-P

Comment: @deceze - you probably misunderstood me when i said that i know that it is impossible. You tell **obvious** things. I just try to analyze how phpBB has implemented this constants. That's all.

Comment: what does phpBB has to do with this all of a sudden? Just one more proof that your question is unclear.

Comment: @Gordon - read comments to the answer. Anyway I already got the point that i was trying to set a constant when it has been already set. So you can continue downvote - i do not care. But if you got problem, and you don't understand you can just ask to explain it better (just an advise).

Comment: How about you update your question with relevant information instead of whining about justified downvotes? People here are usually eager to help but they are are usually not that fond of having to guess what OPs may want to ask. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: @abc I can only tell you obvious things because these obvious things are your answer. As you said yourself, it's impossible. I don't know what else I can tell you except that you can't use constants for what you (seem to) want to use them for.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton class or not, constants are global and *constant*. Once `define`d they can't be undefined or altered. If you need to alter the value, use a *variable*. In this case, probably a `static` class variable.

---

Judging by your comments, you seems to have a misconception of when constants are defined.

Possible:

```
define('FOO', rand());
```

The constant will have a different value *each time the script is executed* (each time a page is visited).

Not possible:

```
define('FOO', 'bar');
define('FOO', 'baz');
```

Constants can't be changed *during the same request*.

Comment: So how for example phpBB redefines their IS_GUEST constant inside their session class? `define('IS_GUEST', (!$this->data['session_logged_in']));`

Comment: @abc Does the value of that constant *change while the script is running*? The above just defines the constant, but the value may differ each time it's defined (on each script run). As far as I understand you, you want to change the value of the constant after it has been defined, which is not possible.

Comment: They define IS_GUEST constant at the first time you enter the site. When you log in, it is changed to FALSE. It doesn't change until user take some action.

Comment: @abc I think you need to realize that each page request is a completely new instance of your script. You can only define a constant once. The thing is that PHP forgets all data, variables, constants and simply *everything* once a page has been processed and sent to the browser. The constant is defined every single time somebody visits a page, and only once each time.

Comment: As I said i call the function **baz()**. It changes the value of $status. So status **is dynamic**. And HELLO value depends on **status**.

Comment: @abc So you want this to work? `$foo = Foo::getInstance(); $foo->baz();` `HELLO` should now have a different value than when it was `setUp`?